# Python Monthly Change Calculation (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Here is data

| id | date | population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-5 | 21 |
| 2 | 2021-5 | 22 |
| 3 | 2021-5 | 23 |
| 4 | 2021-5 | 24 |
| 1 | 2021-4 | 17 |
| 2 | 2021-4 | 24 |
| 3 | 2021-4 | 18 |
| 4 | 2021-4 | 29 |
| 1 | 2021-3 | 20 |
| 2 | 2021-3 | 29 |
| 3 | 2021-3 | 17 |
| 4 | 2021-3 | 22 |

I want to calculate the monthly change regarding population in each id. so result will be:

| id | date | delta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | .2353 |
| 1 | 4 | -.15 |
| 2 | 5 | -.1519 |
| 2 | 4 | -.2083 |
| 3 | 5 | .2174 |
| 3 | 4 | .0556 |
| 4 | 5 | -.2083 |
| 4 | 4 | .3182 |

delta := (this month - last month) / last month

How to approach this in pandas? I'm thinking of groupby but don't know what to do next

remember there might be more dates. but results is always

Comment: Why is it `../ this month` instead of `../last month` ? Doesn't `last month` makes more sense ?

Comment: oh yeah (this month - last month) / last month. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: You'd call that ***relative monthly change*** in population.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.pct_change.html) with sorting columns first before, last remove misisng rows by column `delta`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(['id','date'], ascending=[True, False])

df['delta'] = df.groupby('id')['population'].pct_change(-1)

df = df.dropna(subset=['delta'])
print (df)
   id       date  population     delta
0   1 2021-05-01          21  0.235294
4   1 2021-04-01          17 -0.150000
1   2 2021-05-01          22 -0.083333
5   2 2021-04-01          24 -0.172414
2   3 2021-05-01          23  0.277778
6   3 2021-04-01          18  0.058824
3   4 2021-05-01          24 -0.172414
7   4 2021-04-01          29  0.318182
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try something like:

```
data['delta'] = data['population'].diff()
data['delta'] /= data['population']
```

with this approach the first line would be NaNs, but for the rest, this should work.

Comment: Sorry. i edited the problem to above. :) more complete problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
df.groupby('id')['population'].rolling(2).apply(lambda x: (x.iloc[0] - x.iloc[1]) / x.iloc[0]).dropna()
```